# What's a short way to prepend 3 bytes to the beginning of a binary file in C?

Tags: c

The straightforward way I know of is to create a new file, write the three bytes to it, and then read the original file into memory (in a loop) and write it out to the new file.

Is there a faster way that would either permit skipping the creation of a new file, or skip reading the original file into memory and writing back out again?

Comment: I'm sure you have a very good reason, but may I ask why? Perhaps there are alternate solutions worth considering such as resource forks, alternate streams, etc. depending on the filesystem you're targeting?

Comment: This is more of a curiosity question, because I was writing this hack to work around a limitation in one of the internal systems at my company, and I wondered if it could be done with less code.

Comment: The simple solution has the additional benefit of being the most reliable.

Answer (score 1):

There is, unfortunately, no way (with POSIX or standard libc file APIs) to insert or delete a range of bytes in an existing file.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't so much about C as about filesystems; there aren't many common filesystem APIs that provide shortcuts for prepending data, so in general the straightforward way is the only one.

You may be able to use some form of memory-mapped I/O appropriate to your platform, but this trades off one set of problems for another (such as, can you map the entire file into your address space or are you forced to break it up into chunks?).

Answer (score 0):

You could open the file as read/write, read the first 4KB, seek backward 4KB, write your three bytes, write (4KB - 3) bytes, and repeat the process until you reach the end of the file.

Comment: And good luck recovering if the process doing this gets killed before it finishes... :-(